# Is it possible to use flex-wrap and also add ellipses to indicate the items are wrapped?

Tags: css, text, flexbox, overflow

[Something like this: Imagine the third element is wrapped an we show an ellipses for it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKmII.png)

If these are the items:

```css
.container { 
  height: 50px; 
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.item {
  text-overflow: clip;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
  margin: 0px 5px 10px 5px;
}

.item.injected {
  flex:1;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0px 5px 10px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div> 
  <div class="item injected">Info 4</div>
</div>
```

But we want that while wrapping the last element does not get wrapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex-wrap and ellipses in CSS both are different things.

Yes, You can use both flex-wrap and ellipses in CSS.

"**Flex-wrap**" property is used to specify whether flex items are forced into a single line or wrapped onto multiple lines. The flex-wrap property allows enabling the control direction in which lines are stacked. It is used to designate a single line or multi-line format to flex items inside the flex container.

"**ellipses**" is displayed inside the content area, decreasing the amount of text displayed.

I have created an example, you can reach out by clicking below link:

`example`https://jsfiddle.net/zuqf6v8k/1/

Comment: I guess the question was not so clear.. The question is if the ellipses can be displayed outside the content area.. As to indicate that a few items have been wrapped to the next line which might not be visible to user as the height of parent container is just to accommodate single line only.

Comment: Something similar to what i have shown in attached image.